# stacking/melting multiple columns into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2, melt

I am trying to melt/stack/gather multiple specific columns of a dataframe into 2 columns, retaining all the others.
I have tried many, many answers on stackoverflow without success (some below). I basically have a situation similar to this post here:
[Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns)
only many more columns to retain and combine. It is important to mention my year columns are factors and I have many, many more columns than the sample listed below so I want to call column names not positions.

```
>df
ID Code Country     year.x   value.x  year.y value.y year.x.x value.x.x              
1  A    USA         2000     34.33422 2001 35.35241  2002   42.30042 
1  A    Spain       2000     34.71842 2001 39.82727  2002   43.22209 
3  B    USA         2000     35.98180 2001 37.70768  2002   44.40232 
3  B    Peru        2000     33.00000 2001 37.66468  2002   41.30232 
4  C    Argentina   2000     37.78005 2001 39.25627  2002   45.72927 
4  C    Peru        2000     40.52575 2001 40.55918  2002   46.62914
```

I tried using the pivot_longer in tidyr based on the post above which seemed very similar, which resulted in various errors depending on what I did:

```
pivot_longer(df, 
             cols = -c(ID, Code, Country), 
             names_to = c(".value", "group"),
             names_sep = ".")
```

I also played with melt in reshape2 in various ways which either melted only the values columns or only the years columns. Such as:

```
new.df <- reshape2:::melt(df, id.var = c("ID", "Code", "Country"), measure.vars=c("value.x", "value.y", "value.x.x", "value.y.y", "value.x.x.x", "value.y.y.y"), value.name = "value", variable.vars=c('year.x','year.y', "year.x.x", "year.y.y", "year.x.x.x", "year.y.y.y", "value.x", variable.name = "year")
```

I also tried dplyr gather based on other posts but I find it extremely difficult to understand the help page and posts. 
To be clear what I am looking to achieve:

```
ID Code Country  year   value                
1  A    USA      2000   34.33422  
1  A    Spain    2000   34.71842  
3  B    USA      2000   35.98180  
3  B    Peru     2000   33.00000  
4  C    Argentina2000   37.78005  
4  C    Peru     2000   40.52575 
1  A    USA      2001   35.35241  
1  A    Spain    2001   39.82727  
3  B    USA      2001   37.70768  
3  B    Peru     2001   37.66468  
4  C    Argentina2001   39.25627  
4  C    Peru     2001   40.55918 
1  A    USA      2002   42.30042  
etc.
```

I really appreciate the help here.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57549204/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54816348/5325862

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gather multiple sets of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns)

Comment: That post has the same answer as I provided above.

Comment: @KNN If you are updating the example, please do keep the original one because updating and removing the original input example is kind of defeating the original answer's effort

Comment: That post has 5 answers, and was then marked as a duplicate of one with 7 answers. None of those can be adapted to help? Have you tried escaping the `.` in your separator, since it's a regex special character?

Comment: As far as I can see with the updates on the OP's post, it is not a dupe

Comment: This has become a pretty different question since the updates. In its current state, I agree with @akrun and am retracting my close vote. But that's why it's helpful for the question you post initially to be the one you actually want answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can specify the `names_pattern`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%  
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, Code, Country),
       names_to = c(".value", "group"),names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*)")
```

---

Or use the `names_sep` with escaped `.` as according to `?pivot_longer`

> names_sep - names_sep takes the same specification as separate(), and can either be a numeric vector (specifying positions to break on), or a single string (specifying a regular expression to split on).

which implies that by default the regex is **on** and the `.` in regex matches any character and not the literal dot.  To get the literal value, either escape or place it inside square bracket

```
pivot_longer(df, 
         cols = -c(ID, Code, Country), 
          names_to = c(".value", "group"),
          names_sep = "\\.")
# A tibble: 18 x 6
#      ID Code  Country   group  year value
#   <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 A     USA       x      2000  34.3
# 2     1 A     USA       y      2001  35.4
# 3     1 A     USA       z      2002  42.3
# 4     1 A     Spain     x      2000  34.7
# 5     1 A     Spain     y      2001  39.8
# 6     1 A     Spain     z      2002  43.2
# 7     3 B     USA       x      2000  36.0
# 8     3 B     USA       y      2001  37.7
# 9     3 B     USA       z      2002  44.4
#10     3 B     Peru      x      2000  33  
#11     3 B     Peru      y      2001  37.7
#12     3 B     Peru      z      2002  41.3
#13     4 C     Argentina x      2000  37.8
#14     4 C     Argentina y      2001  39.3
#15     4 C     Argentina z      2002  45.7
#16     4 C     Peru      x      2000  40.5
#17     4 C     Peru      y      2001  40.6
#18     4 C     Peru      z      2002  46.6
```

#### Update

For the updated dataset

```
library(stringr)
df2 %>% 
   rename_at(vars(matches("year|value")), ~ 
     str_replace(., "^([^.]+\\.[^.]+)\\.([^.]+)$", "\\1\\2")) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, Code, Country),
        names_to = c(".value", "group"),names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*)")
```

Or without the `rename`, use regex lookaround

```
df2 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, Code, Country), 
       names_to = c(".value", "group"),
           names_sep = "(?<=year|value)\\.")
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Code = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), Country = c("USA", "Spain", "USA", 
"Peru", "Argentina", "Peru"), year.x = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L), value.x = c(34.33422, 34.71842, 35.9818, 
33, 37.78005, 40.52575), year.y = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L), value.y = c(35.35241, 39.82727, 37.70768, 37.66468, 
39.25627, 40.55918), year.z = c(2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L), value.z = c(42.30042, 43.22209, 44.40232, 41.30232, 45.72927, 
46.62914)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))



df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Code = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), Country = c("USA", "Spain", "USA", 
"Peru", "Argentina", "Peru"), year.x = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L), value.x = c(34.33422, 34.71842, 35.9818, 
33, 37.78005, 40.52575), year.y = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L), value.y = c(35.35241, 39.82727, 37.70768, 37.66468, 
39.25627, 40.55918), year.x.x = c(2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L), value.x.x = c(42.30042, 43.22209, 44.40232, 41.30232, 
45.72927, 46.62914)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: So I should have added that my columns continue as such: value.x.x.x and year.x.x.x, value.y.y.y, year.y.y.y, etc. That is from a previous left_join.

Comment: I know. I was trying to simplify the many columns I had for the example so it was my mistake.

Comment: @KNN  As you can see, the `names_pattern` I provided is based on the pattern you showed

Comment: I updated the question to include more column names.

Comment: Okay I see what you did. Is there a way to make the  str_replace() regex just match everything before the first period so not having to add that pattern for every .? So it is compatible with value.x, value.x.x, value.x.x.x, value.x.x.x.x, etc.?

Comment: @KNN Can you please check my update  `Or without the rename, use regex lookaround`

Comment: @KNN No problem.  I think the dupes linked are not at all dupes for this question