# Using Tidyr's pivot_longer_spec for parameters stored in multiple column names for one observation

Tags: r, tidyr

Fairly new to R but from my research I believe this is a unique question.

I am working with water quality data that is provided to me by another agency in a wide format which looks like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hablar)

wq.data<-as.data.frame(read.csv('C:/WQdata.csv',stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

wq.data<-wq.data%>%
  convert(chr(1:8))

wq.data
# A tibble: 9 x 8
  Station.ID SampleTime       AreaName   Sample.Depth.m Temp.Mid.degC Temp.Mid.Q DO.mg.l DO.Q 
  <chr>      <chr>            <chr>      <chr>          <chr>         <chr>      <chr>   <chr>
1 220        07/09/2019 14:44 Blue River 1.5            29.69         ""         1.66    ""   
2 220        06/10/2019 14:17 Blue River 2.1            28.67         K          3.62    ""   
3 220        05/22/2019 14:31 Blue River 1.7            29.63         ""         7.66    LP   
4 220        04/08/2019 14:15 Blue River 1.7            25.9          ""         6.27    ""   
5 220        03/13/2019 14:19 Blue River 1.4            23.04         K          5.51    ""   
6 220        02/13/2019 14:34 Blue River 2              20.17         ""         6.05    L    
7 220        01/15/2019 14:16 Blue River 1.7            18.75         MK         5.45    ""   
8 220        12/10/2018 14:53 Blue River 1.1            20.18         ""         5.64    ""   
9 220        11/14/2018 14:43 Blue River 1.1            27.43         ""         5.62    ""
```

I converted to `chr` to avoid issues of the data having no common type. You will see that besides the observation data included in `Station.ID`, `SampleTime`, and `AreaName`, the rest of the data includes both the parameter and units in the column name, which I want to extract. Most columns have an associated column for which the name always ends with `Q` (i.e. `Temp.Mid.Q`), which stands for Qualifier and is the QA/QC codes which match that specific observation and are important to keep with each observation.

This is only a subset, the actual data is much wider with many more parameters.

Ideally, I am looking for an end product like this:

```
  Station.ID       SampleTime   AreaName    Parameter Units Value Qualifier
1        220 07/09/2019 14:44 Blue River Sample.Depth     m  1.50          
2        220 07/09/2019 14:44 Blue River     Temp.Mid  degC 29.69          
3        220 07/09/2019 14:44 Blue River           DO  mg.l  1.66          
4        220 06/10/2019 14:17 Blue River Sample.Depth     m  2.10          
5        220 06/10/2019 14:17 Blue River     Temp.Mid  degC 28.67         K
6        220 06/10/2019 14:17 Blue River           DO  mg.l  3.62          
7        220 05/22/2019 14:31 Blue River Sample.Depth     m  1.70          
8        220 05/22/2019 14:31 Blue River     Temp.Mid  degC 29.63          
9        220 05/22/2019 14:31 Blue River           DO  mg.l  7.66        LP
```

I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291060/stacking-melting-multiple-columns-into-multiple-columns-in-r) question on stacking/melting multiple columns would help, but there the column names at least have a standard `value` and `year`. I am not familiar with regex syntax which may or may not be helpful here.

So, since I need to extract the parameters from my column names, I have resorted to attempting to do this "by hand" using an intermediary `spec` data frame as described near the end of the [Tidyr Pivoting Vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html).

I began by creating the following `spec`:

```
spec<-tribble(
  ~.name,                           ~.value,  ~parameter,          ~units,
  "Sample.Depth.m",                 "value",  "Sample.Depth",      "m",
  "Temp.Mid.degC",                  "value",  "Temp.Mid",          "deg.C",
  "DO.mg.l",                        "value",  "DO",                "mg.l",
  "Temp.Mid.Q",                     "Qual",   NA,                  NA,
  "DO.Q",                           "Qual",   NA,                  NA,
)
```

However, perhaps obviously, when I execute:

```
wq.data.longer<-pivot_longer_spec(wq.data,spec)
```

I am returned with an extra row with `NA` inserted but the actual Qualifier character is absent from `Qual` and no longer associated with a specific observation:

```
wq.data.longer
# A tibble: 36 x 7
   Station.ID SampleTime       AreaName   parameter    units value Qual 
   <chr>      <chr>            <chr>      <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 220        07/09/2019 14:44 Blue River Sample.Depth m     1.5   NA   
 2 220        07/09/2019 14:44 Blue River Temp.Mid     deg.C 29.69 NA   
 3 220        07/09/2019 14:44 Blue River DO           mg.l  1.66  NA   
 4 220        07/09/2019 14:44 Blue River NA           NA    NA    ""   
 5 220        06/10/2019 14:17 Blue River Sample.Depth m     2.1   NA   
 6 220        06/10/2019 14:17 Blue River Temp.Mid     deg.C 28.67 NA   
 7 220        06/10/2019 14:17 Blue River DO           mg.l  3.62  NA   
 8 220        06/10/2019 14:17 Blue River NA           NA    NA    ""   
 9 220        05/22/2019 14:31 Blue River Sample.Depth m     1.7   NA   
10 220        05/22/2019 14:31 Blue River Temp.Mid     deg.C 29.63 NA   
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Recall my Qualifier would ideally show here in row 6 (for the above view) if all was correct:

```
  Station.ID SampleTime       AreaName   parameter    units value Qual  
6 220        06/10/2019 14:17 Blue River Temp.Mid     deg.C 28.67 K
```

This may be a fairly simple solution but I haven't been able to make any progress. Any assistance is very much appreciated. I haven't found evidence of many others using `pivot_longer_spec` nor much more guidance from the Tidyr vignette so I'm generally curious how to get farther with this method.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just need to add the names for the `parameter` and `units` columns in your `spec` rather than `NA`

```
spec <- tribble(
  ~.name, ~ .value, ~ parameter, ~ units,
  "Sample.Depth.m", "value", "Sample.Depth", "m",
  "Temp.Mid.degC", "value", "Temp.Mid", "deg.C",
  "DO.mg.l", "value", "DO", "mg.l",
  "Temp.Mid.Q", "Qual", "Temp.Mid", "deg.C",
  "DO.Q", "Qual", "DO", "mg.1",
)

pivot_longer_spec(df, spec)

# A tibble: 36 x 7
#   Station.ID SampleTime AreaName   parameter    units value Qual 
#           <int> <fct>      <fct>      <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <chr>
# 1           220 7/9/2019   Blue River Sample.Depth m      1.5  NA   
# 2           220 7/9/2019   Blue River Temp.Mid     deg.C 29.7  ""   
# 3           220 7/9/2019   Blue River DO           mg.l   1.66 NA   
# 4           220 7/9/2019   Blue River DO           mg.1  NA    ""   
# 5           220 6/10/2019  Blue River Sample.Depth m      2.1  NA   
  6           220 6/10/2019  Blue River Temp.Mid     deg.C 28.7  K    
# 7           220 6/10/2019  Blue River DO           mg.l   3.62 NA   
# 8           220 6/10/2019  Blue River DO           mg.1  NA    ""   
# 9           220 5/22/2019  Blue River Sample.Depth m      1.7  NA   
# 10           220 5/22/2019  Blue River Temp.Mid     deg.C 29.6  ""
```

## Data

```
df <- structure(list(Station.ID = c(220L, 220L, 220L, 220L, 220L, 
220L, 220L, 220L, 220L), SampleTime = structure(c(9L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1/15/2019", "11/14/2018", 
"12/10/2018", "2/13/2019", "3/13/2019", "4/8/2019", "5/22/2019", 
"6/10/2019", "7/9/2019"), class = "factor"), X = structure(c(8L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 7L), .Label = c("14:15", "14:16", 
"14:17", "14:19", "14:31", "14:34", "14:43", "14:44", "14:53"
), class = "factor"), AreaName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Blue River", class = "factor"), 
    Sample.Depth.m = c(1.5, 2.1, 1.7, 1.7, 1.4, 2, 1.7, 1.1, 
    1.1), Temp.Mid.degC = c(29.69, 28.67, 29.63, 25.9, 23.04, 
    20.17, 18.75, 20.18, 27.43), Temp.Mid.Q = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "K", 
    "MK"), class = "factor"), DO.mg.l = c(1.66, 3.62, 7.66, 6.27, 
    5.51, 6.05, 5.45, 5.64, 5.62), DO.Q = c("", "", "LP", 
    "", "", "L", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, this seems to have worked!! Does it make sense to you that doing this by hand and creating a spec is the simplest way to do this? Or am I missing something more obvious?

Also, do you know how adding the names for `parameter` and `units` makes this work? I had assumed that would have created another row for each qualifier (as it had with `NA` in my original question.